# Refresh the ListView from the SPFx Extension

Tags: list-view, spfx-extensions, refresh

I have implemented an extension that moves the file to a particular location. everything works fine but once the operation is completed I want to refresh the listView so the file which is moved should not be seen.

I already checked [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243664/how-to-update-listview-within-spfx-commandset-to-show-new-item) post under which it mentioned to use `location.reload()`.

Is there any other way without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Have you tried the solution given [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1449)?

Comment: I tried but the code is giving error for s and __ko part.